# Why should we use BaseEstimator and Transformermixmin from sklearn.base in python to create/ custom class?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am a beginner at learning sklearn from Python. I know we could create any class by ourselves with something like that:

```
class name():
   def __init__(self):
       pass
   def fit(self, x):
          return  something
```

But I cannot understand why when we try to custom the transformer or the class in sklearn we need to use BaseEstimator and Transformermixmin as below:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, Transformermixmin

class name(BaseEstimator, Transformermixmin):
    def __init(self):
       pass
    def fit(self, x):
       return self
```

what is the difference between the empty class and the other one with BaseEstimator, Transformermixmin? How can BaseEstimator and Transformermixmin work and what does it used for? Can someone answer the above questions and give me more examples or clear explanations about them? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You do not **need** to inherit from either class, but they can both be helpful.

`BaseEstimator` implements `get_params` and `set_params` for you, assuming you adhere to the [requirements for the `__init__` method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#instantiation).  These two methods allow your custom transformer to be `clone`d and hyperparameter-tuned using `GridSearchCV` or `RandomizedSearchCV`.  It also provides a printing methods to print either text or html representation of your estimator.  It also contains some common input validation methods, and more recently, feature name handling.

`TransformerMixin` implements `fit_transform` as `fit` followed by `transform`.  It's convenient, although not nearly so much as `BaseEstimator`.

See also the box titled "BaseEstimator and mixins" in the [sklearn developer guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#rolling-your-own-estimator).